# Output string as HTML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string with some HTML markup like this

`<strong>foo</strong>`

and I want the parser to output it as HTML, but `xsl:value-of` writes it out literally. I've set the stylesheet's output property like this

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

but it's not working as I want it to. Suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: Added context. It's a simple parser that takes an input string and separates it into special code (wrapped up inside square brackets) and HTML content. The HTML output is on the line with `<xsl:value-of select="$c" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`

The test string is 
`[ title: "Rady Expertů" ] <strong>Foo</strong>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<!-- parser -->

<xsl:template name="box-parser">
    <xsl:param name="content" />
    <xsl:param name="property" />

    <!-- extract code wrapped up in brackets -->
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="substring-before($content, ']')" />
    <xsl:variable name="b" select="substring-after($a, '[')" />

    <!-- HTML content -->
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="substring-after($content, ']')" />

    <xsl:variable name="output">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- if we want to output HTML content only -->
            <xsl:when test="$property = 'content-only'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$c" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- if we want to output the value of a property -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($b, $property)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($b, $property), '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- error -->
            <xsl:otherwise>promenna '<xsl:value-of select="$property" />' nenalezena</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$output" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the output, what is the xml, what is the xsl and what is the desired output ?

Comment: Please post some context, do you have a node in your input XML, or really a string value with markup? For a node you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="strong"/>`, for a string you need `<xsl:value-of select="$string" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`.

Comment: It's just a string. Disabling output escaping doesn't seem to work, that's why I'm asking. Also added context for you.

Comment: Figured it out while on the toilet, thanks for the downvote and nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Disable output escaping on `$output`

`<xsl:value-of select="$output" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`

Comment: In my opinion, you should give credit to @MartinHonnen for this finding.

Comment: You are welcome. Besides being grateful, you could edit your answer and include this.

Comment: No I won't, as I've already known about output escaping. Goodbye.